# Power Pivot 2010: DAX, Dynamic Groups with Overlap

Tags: relational-database, excel-2010, powerpivot, dax

How do I use Power Pivot to summarize data in groups which are defined in a separate, non-relatable table

I'm analyzing a database that has the following tables:

```
Sales
  Store
  Category
  Units
  Sales
Stores
  Store
  address
  etc
StoreGroups
  Store
  Group
```

A store can be in multiple groups (i.e. store B762 is in NW group & control_group) hence the StoreGroup table - where the two fields together make the primary key. Therefore, I can't relate StoreGroups to my Sales table, because both have duplicate Store values.

Right now all stores are being reported in each group:
[PivotTableScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJlqE.png)

to confirm, if a store is in two groups, its sales *should* get counted for BOTH groups i.e. control group and NWRegion.

I've tried to adapt this DAX example mentioned below but have not been successful:
http://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a many-to-many relationship between stores and groups.

You should be able to create a relationship from the store in StoreGroups and the Store in Stores (StoreGroups is a bridge table).

If you can post a link to some sample data, that would be helpful.

After doing that, you can read start to read about writing DAX formulas for many-to-many scenarios [here](https://powerpivotpro.com/2012/11/a-mystifying-and-awesome-solution-for-many-2-many/). Be sure to also read in the comments, especially the one from Marco Russo.